# WPF-Project System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I hope someone can help me.
I have a WPF-Project (it´s working fine) and i want use it
in another one. But i got a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.

at:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True"
                          Header="Symbols"
                          Margin="0,1,0,0"
                          Content="{StaticResource SymbolStencils}" />
```

my SymbolStencils looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner">

<s:Toolbox x:Key="SymbolStencils"
           DefaultItemSize="55,55">
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Button IsHitTestVisible="False">Button</Button>
        <ComboBox IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Label IsHitTestVisible="False" >Label</Label>
        <ListBox IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Rectangle IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False" >Text</TextBox>
        <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" >Text</TextBlock>
        <RadioButton IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" />          
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</s:Toolbox>
```

Comment: did you include the resource dictionary in your Xaml file where Expander is present?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramDesigner.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Diagram Designer Part 2"
    FontFamily="SegoeUI"
    Height="850"
    Width="1100">
```

Thats my head in the XAML file